# What is maximum size for attachment for mimebodypart in sending email with Gmail API (Java)?

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

I am using Gmail Java SDK for sending email with attachment.

From this document, the maximum of uploading file size is 35 MB. (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send).

However, In the reality, I only can send email with attachment with only 5MB maximum size, beyond that I get 400 Bad Request Too Large error from google.

This is my code for creating the mime message before send:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    email.setRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    email.setSubject(SUBJECT_RE + subject);
    email.setReplyTo(new Address[]{new InternetAddress(from)});
    String references = getMailReferences(messageId, service);
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(references)) {
    email.setHeader(MAIL_HEADER_REFERENCES, references);
    }

    MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    mimeBodyPart.setContent(bodyText, "text/plain");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
    multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

    for(int i=0 ; i< attachments.size() ; i++) {
        EmailAttach attachment = attachments.get(i);
        MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPartAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(attachment.getAttachmentBytes());
        DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(new InputStreamDataSource(inputStream, attachment.getFileName())); 
        mimeBodyPartAttachment.setDataHandler(dataHandler);
        mimeBodyPartAttachment.setFileName(dataHandler.getName());
        multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPartAttachment);
    }

    email.setContent(multipart);
```

Is there any size limitation sending email with attachment with gmail or there is change needed in code to handle big attachment (example handle/creating MimeBodyPart) (>5MB)?

Comment: I would log it as a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025

Comment: Ok, i have reported this issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved, You need to use the method send with AbstractInputStreamContent parameter and DON'T do encode Base64 for the message content:

```
  Message message = createMessageWithEmail(emailContent, threadId);
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        emailContent.writeTo(buffer);
        message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message, new ByteArrayContent("message/rfc822", buffer.toByteArray())).execute();
```